# What is the function of GeoServer's ImageMosaic "imageindex" field?

Tags: geoserver, image-mosaic

I'm trying to use GeoServer's ImageMosaic plugin to serve up some folders of netCDF files with a particular naming convention. Rather than try to rig up some collection of regex-based `PropertyCollectors`, I'd like to manually populate the granule index.

I've noticed that ImageMosaic requires the index table to have an `imageindex` integer field, whose values seem to form a globally unique sequence (i.e., unique across all variables in the mosaic.)

What is the purpose of this field, and is there any requirement on how I populate it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The imageIndex field maps into a per NetCDF index file (located in a sidecar hidden folder) that has the offset from the beginning of file of a particular 2D slice of data in one of ND coverages contained in the NetCDF file.

As such, it's a machine generated field referring to another binary and machine generated file. Long story short, best not to try and set it up by hand.

More info here:
http://geoserver.geo-solutions.it/edu/en/multidim/netcdf/netcdf_basics.html

If you want to automate ingestion of NetCDF files into a mosaic, better use the dedicated REST API instead, see the following:

- https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/blob/2.10.x/doc/en/user/source/rest/examples/curl.rst#creating-an-empty-mosaic-and-harvest-granules
- http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/api/#/1.0.0/structuredcoverages.yaml